# How to call the variable name of a Jbutton

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a school project and I'm using netbeans IDE. In this project my program has a lot of buttons using the same code, but with different names. Instead of re-typing the variable names every time, is there a way to call the name of the button itself?

```
sa1++;
    if(sa1 % 2 == 0) {
        A1.setEnabled(true);
        A1.setBackground(Color.green);
        A1.setOpaque(false);
    }
    else {
        A1.setEnabled(false);
        A1.setBackground(Color.red);
        A1.setOpaque(true);
    }
```

Please note that the buttons go down alphabetically up to 5. Instead of re-typing it, is there a way to have it like:

[Jbutton variable name].setEnabled(true);

So that it takes less time?

<strike>My teacher's curious about this as well</strike>, and it would help with future projects too.
 **EDIT: teacher knows how to do it, I meant he wants to see how I'll figure it out. You guys are a little harsh, no?**

Comment: Seems like the best thing to do right now is find a new class with a new teacher.

Comment: What research have you done. The fact that the teacher doesn't know how to solve this should be very worry some as the answer to all of your problems are resolved with the basic understanding of Java through basic training.

Comment: Raiden Taki, we are nice people :). anyway, it's just that you've written it in the wrong way. However, having edited the question everything makes sense now. Hopefully, the answers provided helps you out. Good luck with your journey into java. :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the buttons in an array:

```
//change the 5 to however many buttons you want to have
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[5];
```

Then initialize them:

```
buttons[0] = new JButton();
//add any other initialization, like event handlers
```

Then loop through them like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    //replace the line below with whatever you want to do with each button
    performSomeAction(buttons[i]);
}
```

Combining this with another good answer below, you can also make a method to encapsulate everything you want to do to the button:

```
private void performSomeAction(JButton button) {
    if(sa1 % 2 == 0) {
        button.setEnabled(true);
        button.setBackground(Color.green);
        button.setOpaque(false);
    }
    else {
        button.setEnabled(false);
        button.setBackground(Color.red);
        button.setOpaque(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> In this project my program has a lot of buttons using the same code,
>   but with different names. Instead of re-typing the variable names
>   every time, is there a way to call the name of the button itself?

Refactor it into a method.

**Example:**

```
public void TestMethod(JButton button)
    if(sa1 % 2 == 0) {
        button.setEnabled(true);
        button.setBackground(Color.green);
        button.setOpaque(false);
    }
    else {
        button.setEnabled(false);
        button.setBackground(Color.red);
        button.setOpaque(true);
    }
}
```

Then, simply each time call the method and pass in the appropriate button reference.

**Example:**

```
TestMethod(A1);
TestMethod(A2);
TestMethod(A3);
TestMethod(A4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add them to a `List` and do a foreach loop.